# Access Violation at glBindBuffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, access-violation

I've been working on a program using OpenGL for a while now and I recently started getting an error occasionally on this line:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indexID);
```

Here is the error that comes up, though I don't think it'll help too much:

> First-chance exception at `0x0000000069E03C13` (nvoglv64.dll) in
>   Voxel.exe: `0xC0000005`: Access violation reading location
>   `0x000000000AA87000`.

The address given for the access violation varies, and the time it takes for the violation to occur also varies. Given that the time it takes for the access violation to occur varies, I'm guessing it has to do with two threads trying to access the same data, but there's never any other thread working on the same object when the violation occurs, and I'm using mutexes to make sure that two threads can't write to the same data. I've checked and made sure that the ID for index buffer is valid, and since the only thread that generates and deletes buffer IDs is also the only thread that binds and transfers data into the buffers, I don't believe it's possible for the access violation to be because of that.

How can I track down and/or fix what's causing this access violation?

Comment: And m_indexID is valid/correct?

Comment: Every time I've had the access violation, m_indexId has been valid.

Comment: Ok, so does the problem go away if you don't use multiple threads?

Comment: Do you have an active OpenGL context / window when you call this function? i.e. are you making the context 'current' for the *calling* thread?

Comment: as i can see you have nvidia gfx (best choice for OpenGL) so i doubt is driver related issue. What OS, how many contextes do you have ...? what IDE you use"? (i am using bds2006 C++ and it matters from where you call what function) also had some similar issue with GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding once (change of init location in source code worked it out)

Comment: @BrettHale: I only use one thread for OpenGL functions, and it has a context and window associated with it. I can render stuff, it's just sometimes I get that access violation.

Comment: @Spektre: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7, with only one OpenGL context in my program. I don't think it's a problem with initializing OpenGL/GLEW/GLFW (the libraries I'm using), as I can render normally most of the time.

Comment: try to move OpenGL init stuff to main app code (but after your window is created and use-able !!!) and left the rendering in your thread if it helps... (in my case it was very similar behaviour also every thing worked fine but sometimes crash also on w7 x64 and single context and x32 app and just with ELEMENT_ARRAYS all other buffers never crash)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing it has to do with two threads trying to access the same data,

That would be called a race condition. Race conditions don't cause access violations!

My best bet would be that you're using OpenGL from multiple threads and you're initializing extensions only for one. Windows is a bit tricky when it comes to OpenGL extensions and threads: Function pointers may vary between context and thread. And if you use make use of a function pointer initialized for a different context and/or thread this will happen.

Make sure your extension loading mechanism correctly deals with multiple threads and contexts.

Comment: Whoops, I believe I stated the wrong thing. What I meant was two threads trying to change the same data, or add to a vector at the same time. That has the potential to cause an access violation, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Shadow: Modifying values in the same location: Nope, that would just result in corrupted data but not an access violation. Adding to a vector has the potential to generate an access violation, if the vector data structure and its access functions are not reentrant (that's also one of the reasons why C++11 got threading primitives built in, so that data structures could be implemented reentrant, without relying on OS specific APIs).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. So really the only time that two threads writing to the same variable could cause an access violation is if the first thread causes a vector to move itself in memory to resize itself, then the other thread tries to write to the area that the vector use to be in?

Comment: @Shadow: Exactly that. This is the classical use after free race condition. In a program with explicit memory management it will trigger exceptions rather quickly. But they can become very subtle bugs in environments with implicit memory management. For example when using a garbage collector the write to the other location may (depending on the way the GC works) create an access diversion,

Comment: @Shadow: i.e. the memory location is moved, but a write happens to the old location, which is not cleared immediately; it remains "stable" for some time, until the GC kicks in and cleans up not only the discarded memory of the vector, but "new" references that got written to that part due to the race condition.

Comment: So what are the possible causes of an access violation? Is it only the use of a null pointer or a pointer that points to memory already freed, or are there other possibilities as well? Also, would you by any chance know of any other possible reasons why I occasionally get an access violation on that line (and always only that line), but all my OpenGL code runs on one thread?

Comment: @Shadow: An access violation (or a segmentation fault, as it's called on other operating systems) is the exception that is triggered when a process accesses addresses which have nothing mapped to them, or if the kind of access violates the operations permitted on that mapping (for example write to a read only area). A null pointer always points to a not mapped, or a guard mapped region. But a processes address space is sparse and there are a lot of not mapped regions. Also mappings valid in one thread my be invalid in other threads (thread local storage).

Comment: @Shadow: Alas in your case the problem might be, what I already laid out in my original answer: In Windows extension loaded function addresses are tied to the OpenGL context, and may even vary between threads. If your extension loader can't cope with that, this might be the cause of the problem, because depending on active OpenGL context and thread the function pointers may or may not point to valid addresses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Luckily, I seem to have resolved the problem. I was allocating enough space for sizeof(glm::vec3) * m_uvs.size(), but my UV coordinates were glm::vec2s. After changing that to sizeof(glm::vec2), I haven't had any issues with access violations.